# pandas strip all strings in column that starts with symbols +-

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
    value      result
1    fish      +d de hzd +po
2    duck      +g lo kju +okz -kji
3    mouse     +z gh +k
4    rabbit    +bhh uj +okk
5    donky     -de thb +thy
```

And the expected data should look like:

```
   value      result
1    fish      de hzd 
2    duck      lo kju 
3    mouse     gh 
4    rabbit    uj
5    donky     thb
```

I tried

```
df["result"] = [x.lstrip("+- + aAbBcC") for x in df["result"]
```

but it only strips the first string appeared:

```
    value      result
1    fish      de hzd +po
2    duck      lo kju +okz -kji
3    mouse     gh +k
4    rabbit    uj +okk
5    donky     thb +thy
```

is there a way to fix this, to get the expected data? thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df['result'].replace(to_replace='[+-]\w+', value='', regex=True,inplace=True)
df['result']=df['result'].str.strip()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    value  result
0    fish  de hzd
1    duck  lo kju
2   mouse      gh
3  rabbit      uj
4   donky     thb
```

Comment: This solution leaves extra whitespace in the middle of the string.

Answer (score 2):

We can try using `str.replace` along with `str.strip`:

```py
df["result"] = df["result"].str.replace(r'\s*[+-]\S+\s*', '').str.strip()
print(df)
```

This prints:

```
    value  result
0    fish  de hzd
1    duck  lo kju
2   mouse      gh
3  rabbit      uj
4  donkey     thb
```

Answer (score 1):

```
" ".join([ el for el in df["result"].split() if el.isalpha()]) this should help.
```